# SAS Like Operator: can underscore "_" match a single space?

Tags: sas, sql-like

I know that the underscore wildcard can be used to match a single character, but I'm not sure if it can be used to match a single space? Can anybody help answer this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This seems like the sort of thing you could test out in less than the time it takes to ask the question, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
data test;
x=' ';
run;

proc sql;
select count(1) from test 
    where x like "_";
quit;
```

returns 1.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can match a single space as a character as long as you specify the whole length of the character variable. If you want to use the `_`, when you specify the like operator you would have to include the full details of the length of character.

E.g. If I want to select "black wolf":

```
data work.animals;

    input name $1-16 weight;

    datalines;
    monkey      20
    shark       500
    blue whale  200
    black wolf  120
    buffalo     400
    ;

data work.animals3;
    set animals;
    where name like 'black_wol_';
run;
```

I can use `like 'black_wol_';` which includes the full matching pattern of the character inside the character variable. But, I can't just do `like 'black_'` or `like 'black_wol';`. It won't work because the number of characters in the string are different.

Alternatively, you can use the `%` sign which can specify any number of characters before, after or in the middle of a string. E.g. `where name like '%e';` or `where name like 'blu%e';` can select "blue whale". You can use both `_` and `%` together.